# meteor 0.9.1 , Mongo is not defined inside my custom Package

Tags: meteor

Getting Exception Mongo is not defined inside my custom Package

## CODE

```
ABC = new Mongo.Collection('ABC');
```

## ERROR

```
W20140905-17:49:06.809(5.5)? (STDERR) /home/sandeep/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.27.18sl1cs++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140905-17:49:06.809(5.5)? (STDERR)                       throw(ex);
W20140905-17:49:06.810(5.5)? (STDERR)                             ^
W20140905-17:49:06.810(5.5)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to list all the packages you use in your `package.js` file:

```
Package.onUse(function (api) {
  api.use('mongo', ['client', 'server']);
  ...
});
```

Comment: i mean the 'mongo' dependency for using collections is not documented.

Comment: Right, you need to get used to find information in Meteor source to find informations like that.

Comment: @pajooh: It is, in fact, documented, albeit not very obviously. If you look at `.meteor/packages` in your project, you'll see `meteor-platform`. That is a meta package, and if you go to [its GitHub page](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/meteor-platform) you'll see that it includes `mongo`.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you have space on your HD, That was my problem.

Comment: Can lack of HD space cause `Mongo` to be undefined?