# Meteor 1.0.3.1 "Mongo is not defined"

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm creating a package, all as per the Discover Meteor book: https://book.discovermeteor.com/chapter/creating-a-meteor-package

I got this on my `package.js`

```
api.use(['mongo@1.0.11','minimongo@1.0.6','mongo-livedata@1.0.7','templating@1.0.11'],'client',{ unordered: true });
```

And I got this on my errors.js file:

```
Errors = {
  collection: new Mongo.Collection(null),
  ...
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
W20150206-21:52:14.453(-5)? (STDERR)          
W20150206-21:52:14.454(-5)? (STDERR) /Users/Diego/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.959pzb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150206-21:52:14.454(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150206-21:52:14.454(-5)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150206-21:52:14.456(-5)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
W20150206-21:52:14.456(-5)? (STDERR)     at Package (packages/diegoferreyra:errors/errors.js:2:1)
W20150206-21:52:14.456(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Diego/Documents/htdocs/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/diegoferreyra_errors.js:26:4
W20150206-21:52:14.456(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Diego/Documents/htdocs/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/diegoferreyra_errors.js:35:3
W20150206-21:52:14.456(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Diego/Documents/htdocs/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10
W20150206-21:52:14.456(-5)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150206-21:52:14.456(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/Diego/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.959pzb++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150206-21:52:14.456(-5)? (STDERR)     at /Users/Diego/Documents/htdocs/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:116:5
```

I already checked this error: [meteor 0.9.1 , Mongo is not defined inside my custom Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685985/meteor-0-9-1-mongo-is-not-defined-inside-my-custom-package)

But adding mongo to the array did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I found the (stupid) error:

had done:

```
api.addFiles(['errors.js','errors_list.html','errors_list.js']);
```

should've been:

```
api.addFiles(['errors.js','errors_list.html','errors_list.js'],'client');
```