# Mongo is not defined

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm discovering moteor.js, and I struggle with the basics. So far I just followed the tutorial, and everything is fine until I get to the Collections part. My app is running, mongod is running, but for some reason, the app crashes on this line

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to hannibal.";
};

Template.hello.events({
'click input' : function () {
  if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
    console.log("You pressed the button");
}
});
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
 });
}
```

When I open the page in localhost:3000, I get this message

```
ReferenceError: Mongo is not defined
at app/hannibal.js:1:28
```

Any idea why is it doing this ? I thought it might come from the fact that I'm using meteor for Windows.

Comment: can you post more of your code? what tutorial are you following? url?

Comment: What meteor version does the windows version support? `Mongo.Collection` is somewhat recent, prior to 0.9.1 you have to use `Meteor.Collection`.

Comment: I'm following this tutorial : https://www.meteor.com/try/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an old version of Meteor installed.

Run `meteor update` from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

In >v0.9.1, if you're using `Mongo` in a custom package, check that `package.js` includes `api.use('mongo', [client, server])` inside `onUse`. See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685985/meteor-0-9-1-mongo-is-not-defined-inside-my-custom-package).

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was directly importing Mongo from Meteor as so:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'
```